# Closed form cubic root finder implementation

Tags: math, numerical-methods, polynomial-math

I'm looking for a non-iterative function that finds the real roots of cubic polynomials. So, an implementation of something [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots). 
I could write it myself of course, but if someone already has an implementation and doesn't mind sharing it, that would save me the 1-2 hours I would need to write it, at the cost of that person taking 30 seconds to paste it here, so that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Closed form is so unclean. Have you even *seen* the closed form for the Fibonacci sequence?!?! Also, why one to two hours? What language are you using? If it's Python, you could do it in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Blender: I've seen the closed form for the Fibonacci sequence (we had to prove it's correctness in first year calculus), but what does the Fibonacci sequence have to do with my question? I'm using Java.

Comment: Closed form solutions are pretty ugly. The Fibonacci closed-form function involves square roots (I memorized it, since I had to prove the function too). Recursively defined solutions are much cleaner, and are easy to understand. They may be slower, but you wouldn't use solve a formula if you're looking for speed.

Comment: @Blender: umm, no, closed form solutions are not always uglier than recursive/iterative solutions. Consider unsigned square(unsigned x) {return x*x;} It's closed form, but it's much cleaner than it's recursive counter part: unsigned square(unsigned x) {if (x <= 1) return x; else return square(x - 1)+2*x-1;} (I'm using unsigned because I don't want to type all the code for dealing with negative numbers in a comment).

Comment: I didn't mean that they are *always* cleaner, just more often.